# Is it more efficient to let ajax get the html or get JSON and make the javascript create the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

The title says it all, but basically I use ajax to get information and I don't know if I should have PHP create the HTML which then gets returned to the client and then javascript just plugs it in or if I should have the server just send all the information through JSON and have javascript (jQuery) create all the html that holds it.

Which one is more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Define efficient? In terms of speed? Memory? Some other metric?

Comment: I think the right answer comes when you ask: what's more important, reducing server load or supporting ancient browsers. The time to render in a modern browser won't be an issue (well, I'm sure there are exceptions).

Comment: There are multiple efficiency gains here -- are you looking for bandwidth reduction or perceived performance or client side rendering time?

Comment: Third option is the best one, "3. Do whatever fits the best" !!

Comment: @JerrySeeger I don't think the time to render would even be an issue in ancient browsers that support the JavaScript DOM...

Comment: Deliver data over AJAX; format HTML in the page. Not for optimization reasons, but because that's the most flexible approach.

Comment: @crush - my point was that ancient browsers might not be able to render it at all. But yeah, if the scripting support is there for the ajax call, it's not likely he'll be doing something else that the browser doesn't support.

Comment: @JerrySeeger Sorry, I agree totally. I meant my comment as more of an annotation to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is better practice to serve only the JSON data. Why?

Well, perhaps, you want to hook up a different type of client to your data service.

Maybe you create a mobile app, and it needs the same data, but wants to display it differently.

If you are providing the HTML markup as well, then now your mobile app has to parse the data it wants out of the HTML structure, rather than just dealing with the data right away.

On an efficiency scale, that depends on what you consider **efficient**.

For example, it would be efficient from a bandwidth perspective to only send the JSON. However, it would be more efficient from a processing standpoint on the target client to simply give it an HTML string to display.

If you are considering ever having different clients accessing the same data, though, then you want to create a single data interface that serves JSON (in your case), and allow the client to decide how to present that data.

**Separation of concerns.**